# How to update a CellTable dynamically using GWT

Tags: gwt, dynamic, asynchronous, widget, websocket

Working on a `GWT` app that uses a `CellTable` to display data. I was wondering if it was possible to update this `CellTable` dynamically when data from the database has changed(without a specific button). Maybe each 2 seconds or something like that.

I looked for a while and I'm... :

`onRangeChanged(AsyncDataProvider)` is fired only when the user modify the table. right?

So, am I obliged to implement a solution which uses `WebSocket` like Atmosphere or `gwtEventService`? or is there an other way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right, there is nothing in gwt which links the table with the server side out-of-the-box.

Maybe someday RequestFactory could have a [comet](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=267) server push mechanism so as entities are notified when there are server changes.

So the solution right now is to configure an AsyncDataProvider for your table and use some server push library like you point (I use gwt-atmosphere) to fire an event whenever the data is modified so as the data provider could update the table.

Answer (score 0):

[This guide](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellWidgets.html#data-provider) should help, GWT has a built in way of doing this through a `DataProvider`. There is even a specific `AsyncDataProvider` class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I already saw that and it doesn't make it! because I want to fire the views when the data has changed from the server